# Rails doesn't reset ActiveRecord object (new_record?) after error

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord

This has been asked here before, but it has been 3 years.  Unfortunately we're still back using Rails 2.3.14, so it's a problem I'm having now and it wasn't really answered back then.

I have 2 models...

Organization
Organizationpermissions

In the organizations controller, create method, I have the saving of the Organization and the Organizationpermissions objects wrapped in an Organization transaction.

If the Organization saves fine, without error, but the Organizationpermission object fails, the transaction does not properly roll back the Organization object.  The method new_record? thinks the object is not new anymore, which then forces my form to an update action, which I do not want.

This was asked here in 09...

http://bit.ly/MbYGXd

The outcome was that it was a bug in 2.3.5, but no answer as to how to get around it.

Is there a way around this?

Thanks

**UPDATE:**

Just trying to bump this to the top.  Probably shouldn't have posted on the weekend.  :)

I still can not figure out what to do here.  When an error is raised and it's not in the main object the ActiveRecord object is not set to new_record? and the page doesn't reflect a create anymore, it's now an update, which is definitely not going to work.

I could have sworn there is a way around this but I can't find it in my code anywhere.

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar problem and found that if you wrap the code in nested rollback_active_record_state! blocks then it works as expected.  In my case the transaction was failing in an `after_create` callback.

```
ActiveRecord::Base.transaction do
  @model_a = ModelA.new(params[:model_a])
  @model_b = ModelB.new(params[:model_b])

  @model_a.rollback_active_record_state! do
    @model_b.rollback_active_record_state! do
       @model_a.save!
       @model_b.save!
       ...
    end
  end    

end
```